# Add list of names to dropdown from javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to put names into the `dropdown` list but it seems its not working for me now. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**html:**

```
<select name="status" id="dropdownlist" style="width: 100%;">
   <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

**js:**

```
  success: function(resp)
        {
            alert(resp); // names for example: mile,stone,
            var arr = resp.split(",");
            var list = document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value;
            alert(list); // Null
            list.length = 1;
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                var name = arr[i];
                if(name.length != 0)
                {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.text = option.value = name;
                    list.add(option);
                }
            }
        }
```

`
    **edit:**(some person solution)

`success: function(resp)
                {
                    alert(resp); // names for example: mile,stone,
                    var arr = resp.split(",");
                    var list = $(".dropdownlist");
                    list.length = 1;
                    var html = "";
                    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                    {
                        var name = arr[i];
                        if(name.length != 0)
                        {
                            html += "<option value='" + name + "'>";
                            html += name;
                            html += "</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    $(".dropdownlist").append(html);
                }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` in your code is not referring to the dropdown.

change this

```
var list = document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value;
```

to

```
var list = document.getElementById("dropdownlist");
```

`document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value;` returns the selected items value.

- in your html, you haven't specified any default value for the `<option>`. hence it returns null
- You are trying to append `<option>` to `list` which is null.
- `document.getElementById("dropdownlist");`  returns your `<select>` element, To which  you can append the `<option>`s

*update: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/ThVwD/)*

Comment: can you explain this answer little bit?

Comment: thanks for explaining :).can u help with one thing? a guy posted a answer( i updated my post) and this is also working perfectly but it keep adding same name again and again when i click onto the tab?

Comment: can you do also with getting select using a class and not using id? i need for multiple selects.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("your class name");` will  return an array of matching elements. you can then loop through it.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("your class name");` this don't work for me i have tried so many times. is there any thing in jquery i can do that?

Comment: `$('.your class name')`  will return a jquery object of matching element.` If you are looking for some other functionality try posting another question explaining it, coz this conversation is expanding and SO suggests moving to auto chat :)

Comment: can you please check this fiddle i have above posted. If a post another question like that they gonna mark my question negative for asking again the same thing :p

Comment: yes thats good. i have still one problem left. can i post another question or u will help me here. i put this code in a tab even whenever i click on it the names in the dropdown list increases.